# Codeigniter Email Class - email in spam

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I was using gmail smtp settings to send emails. These settings were working fine until a couple weeks ago, but stopped working all of a sudden. All the outgoing mails are going into the spam folder. Any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if your problem is that emails are going into spam box, you should check some tutorial or read some book on how to send emails correctly to avoid being blacklisted, but the problem is not really related to Codeigniter or PHP ;)

I mean it depends on many factors out of the programming languages, like content you send, if images are inside your content, how much is rated your website/IP, which is the title you put in your emails, which email address you use to send the emails ... etc etc , `and *+obvously** how many people receives your emails and put you in spam flagging the email as SPAM :P`

Comment: HAHA..yeah..i was just sending an email to one user. Any way, i added this email to trusted lists and that did the trick. Thanks for the info.