# Spam issue in email functionality with SMTP in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, email, codeigniter-3

I am working on email functionality, for that i have set SMTP, email is working for gmail, but for the email providers mail is going to spam folder, can anyone please help what i need to do to resolve that issue ? here is my code for that

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp'; 
            $config['smtp_host'] = SMTP_HOST; 
            $config['smtp_user'] = SMTP_USER; 
            $config['smtp_pass'] = SMTP_PASSWORD; 
            $config['smtp_port'] = '587';
            $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
            $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

            $this->load->library('email', $config);

            $this->email->set_header('Content-Type', 'text/html');

            $this->email->from(FROM_EMAIL);
            $this->email->to($email);
            $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
            $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
            $this->email->subject("Test email");
            $this->email->message("Testing Mail received.");

            if($this->email->send()){
                echo "Email send.";
            } else {
                echo "Error";
            }
```

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998951/codeigniter-email-class-email-in-spam?rq=1

Comment: Are you using the Gmail address you are logging in to the smtp server with as the sender (email->from())? If not, that is likely the cause of your deliverability issues.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try settings of SMTP like this.
This code works for me.

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMPTAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = "my@email.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
```

Comment: I mean it's sending mail in primary inbox folder not in spam.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please try this..

```
            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';

            $config['smtp_host'] = 'SMTP_USER';

            $config['smtp_port'] = '587';

            $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';

            $config['smtp_user'] = 'SMTP_USER';

            $config['smtp_pass'] = 'SMTP_PASSWORD';

            $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';

            $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

            $config['mailtype'] = 'html'; // or html

            $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not      

            $this->email->initialize($config);
            $this->email->from('SMTP_USER', 'Name');
            $this->email->to($emailTo);

            $this->email->subject('subject here');



            $this->email->message('message here');


            $this->email->send();
```

Comment: load  email library       $this->load->library('email');

Answer (score 0):

Try this configuration

```
        $config = array(
         'protocol'      => 'SMTP',
         'mailtype'      => 'html',
         'smtp_host'     => '*********',
         'smtp_port'     => '********',
         'charset'       => 'UTF-8',
         'newline'       => "\r\n",
         'auth'          => true, 
         'mailpath'      => '/usr/sbin/sendmail',
         'validate'      => 'FALSE',
       );



        $this->email->clear();
        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n"); 
        $this->email->initialize($config); 
        $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
        $this->email->set_crlf( "\r\n" );
        $this->email->from("*****", "*****");
        $this->email->to($row->email);
        $this->email->subject("******");
        $this->email->message($mesg);
```